# How create 2nd host in NuoDB

Tags: nuodb

Can anybody tell me how to setup two hosts in one machine. Till now I have installed NuoDB with two hosts option, created a database in one host and loaded data, but don't know how to create other hosts. How these 2 hosts will connect with each other?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run NuoDB on 2 machines you need 2 physical or virtual machines.  If you have a single host, you can run a virtual machine on that host to provide the 2nd machine.

Once you have multiple hosts, you can follow the instructions in the NuoDB documentation for configuring a NuoDB domain with more than one host:
http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/Adding+Hosts+to+a+NuoDB+Domain

There is also a nice blog post describing this as well: http://dev.nuodb.com/techblog/2013/03/11/getting-started-provisioning-a-domain

-Adam